# Intercept http traffic with selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium, http-proxy

I am building an web application testing tool in Selenium, using the chrome webdrive in Python 3.5. So far the application is working properly, but the marketing team is telling me that it is affecting web analytics metrics. As I am crawling the pages, it is sending requests to our web analytics platform.

What would be the best approach to collect that the web analytics tag is being trigged (the request itself), but actually not send the request ?

Is using a proxy to intercept and block the request from being send a possible solution?

Edit:
The metric system is Google Analytics, the call looks like the following

https://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect?

After the ? comes the parameters to be sent to google analytics. But every time this url is called, a page view is registered.

Comment: You should share some details on how that metrics system actually works.

Comment: Why is the instance of the application you're testing instrumented with analytics? I would expect only production deployments to have analytics, and I would expect you wouldn't be running WebDriver tests against your production stack on an operational basis.

Comment: Tell them to exclude the IPs of the machines you are using to run automation or if you are running automation internally, they should already exclude all internal IPs.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the ***Chrome-Developer-Protocoll*** for request interception. It desn't use a proxy.
You can filter specific requests or responses by url or type to get paused
Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75067388/20443541.